# Create a view to display the list of content created by user

Tags: 7, users, nodes, views

I want to create a view for each individual user of my site which would display the content create by that logged in user only, i.e, When a user logs in, then when he clicks a tab (i am using quicktab here) a view appears which shows all the content that this user only has created. I do not want to show this user content created by others. Is there any efficient way to do so. I am using Views3.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way to list content created by user is with Views.

Basically, create your view, with the relevant filters for content type, fields etc..

Then add a contextual filter for current user.

- Click "Advanced" > "Contextual Filters"
- "Add" > "Content: Author uid"
- "Provide default value" > "User ID from logged in user"
- Save

[image: User ID contextual filter]

Comment: @David...Thanks...i also figured it out...thanks for the quick and prompt reply...appreciate it

Comment: What if we want to list content from another user, not the actual logged in user? for exemple in the article view page, also list additional content for tha user